# GStreamer cant be resolved error in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, gstreamer

I've imported the tutorials from the gst-sdk folder in eclipse. But even after adding native support, i'm getting the error import to gstreamer cant be resolved. 
The error is basically make.exe has stopped working. Hence, eclipse closes. So,i think the root problem occurs during th e phase of add native support. After that only, am not able to build my application or solve the errors.

Comment: Please edit your answer and paste in the exact error text that the program is giving you.

Answer (score 0):

There are currently issues with building ndk applications in Eclipse if you use Eclipse Juno or are running on Windows see the [Using the NDK Plugin](http://tools.android.com/recent/usingthendkplugin) page for more information.

I have been able to get the tutorials to build and run by disabling the CDT builder in the Eclipse project and building the GStreamer libraries by running ndk-make via the command line. You can find more information in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14862795/unable-to-build-gstreamer-for-android-tutoritals).