# Compiling Gstreamer Android tutorial gst/gst.h missing

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk, gstreamer

I'm currently trying to compile the first tutorial of Gstreamer but it doesn't work on my computer. I'm on Ubuntu with Eclipse. I have installed SDK et NDK Android and added to the path GSTRAMER_SDK_ROOT_ANDROID and ANDROID_NDK_HOME.

But the problem is in my Android.mk . The file gst/gst.h is not found :/
I have searched it in my folder "gstreamer-sdk-android-arm-debug-2013.6" I have downloaded from gstreamer website. And this file is in gstreamer-0.10.

How can I say to Eclipse to look into /include/gstreamer-0.10 rather than /include/gst/gst.h

( And it is the same with glib.h and other files ... :/ )

Someone has the solution please?

Answer (score 1):

Added this:

`LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES += $(GSTREAMER_SDK_ROOT)/include/gstreamer-0.10
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES += $(GSTREAMER_SDK_ROOT)/include/glib-2.0
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES += $(GSTREAMER_SDK_ROOT)/lib/glib-2.0/include 
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES += $(GSTREAMER_SDK_ROOT)/include/libxml2/`

after

`LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES += $(GSTREAMER_SDK_ROOT)/include`

in `gstreamer-sdk-android-arm-debug-2013.6/share/gst-android/ndk-build/gstreamer.mk`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, but that was just a symptom of the real problem: `pkg-config: command not found`. Per the answer at [Unable to build GStreamer for Android Tutorials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14862795/unable-to-build-gstreamer-for-android-tutorials), pkg-config is not bundled with the GStream libs, so you need to install it separately for things to work. Here are my logs from the error:

```
/bin/sh: pkg-config: command not found
gst-build-arm64-v8a/gstreamer_android.c:2:10: fatal error: 'gst/gst.h' file not found
#include <gst/gst.h>
```

I installed pkg-config using Mac Ports `sudo port install PkgConfig`, but brew or other installation techniques should work fine.

Comment: Strange thing: I have pkg-config installed, it runs at bash level. Not from the gradle build. Getting the same error "pkg-config.not found" Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Several things to check:

1. GSTRAMER_SDK_ROOT_ANDROID should be GSTREAMER_SDK_ROOT_ANDROID. Double check that you spelled it correctly.
2. Make sure Eclipse is pointing to the correct NDK. Go to Window -> Preferences -> Android -> NDK and point it to your NDK
3. In my experience, the latest NDK (r10e) doesn't work, because a method was taken out that gets used by the GStreamer tutorials. You can get a previous version that works here (r9d):  https://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk-r9d-windows-x86_64.zip
4. Right-click the root folder of the tutorial 1 in Eclipse. Go to: Android Tools -> Add Native Support. Then in the popup window click ok. Clean. Build.